# Nokia Series 40 persistent storage

Tags: java-me, nokia, persistent-storage, rms

I have a question about persistent storage for Java applications on the Nokia [Series 40](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_40) platform. Who takes care of cleaning the persistent storage (RMS) of an application when it is deleted (Collection->options->Delete)?

I know there is no explicit application manager on Series 40 (as compared to [S60](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S60_%28software_platform%29)) and, from user perspective, deleting an application is very similar to deleting an image file, for example. So is persistent storage data cleared automatically by the Series 40 OS upon application deletion? Is there a way to preserve this data when an application is deleted and possibly use it again if the application is installed again?

P.S.: I read almost all of the Java developer's library, but I couldn't find an explicit aswer - it only said that all associated persistent storage must be removed when a [MIDlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDlet) is removed, but who does that? By contrast, the S60 developer's library says explicitly that on S60 the application and persistent storage are both removed by the application manager.

Comment: works same way both on Symbian and Series 40, application manager removes the all the data associated with the midlet.

Answer (score 2):

When the MIDlet is removed/uninstalled by the user, the operating system will also remove  the associated RMS data.

There is no workaround for keeping the RMS on the device, if the related application has been removed from the device. If you wish to retain the data, write it to a separate file using JSR-75 (FileConnection API), or a network service.